# Testing Function for speed performance in CPP

Tags: c++, c++11, performance-testing

I have created a simple function to convert any lowercase letter a-z to uppercase, the problem may not be a problem but every test returns 0. If I add system("pause") I can see a new value indicating the length of pause.

Is there a more accurate way to test the speed, or is this actually correct? I would like to compare it to other functions to see if it converts faster then standard functions.

```
char* ToUppercase(char* Input)
{
    int Len = Length(Input);
    for (int i = 0; i < Len; i++)
    {
        short keycode = static_cast<short>(Input[i]);
        if (keycode >= 97 && keycode <= 122)
            Input[i] -= 32;
    }
    return Input;
}
```

The current timer I use to test is (created by someone else)

```
template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};
```

To call I use:

```
void Debug()
{
    char Buffer[10000] = "aaaa /..../ aaaa";
    MyStringControl::ToUppercase(Buffer);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << measure<std::chrono::nanoseconds>::execution(Debug);
}
```

Comment: Did you look at `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`?

Comment: I have and it still returned 0. I started wondering if maybe the speed was to fast (quad core i7 cpu) and so I used this:
start high_res_clock
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    MyStringControl::ToUppercase(Buffer);
cout << end high_res_clock

Doing this I got the output 17008

Comment: Does my code below give 0 on your system? I'm also on a fast core i7 (3.5 GHz) - still shouldn't be 0. :) (I just edited to have the Release times instead of Debug and mine is still non-zero.)

Comment: I noticed the comment "<chrono> fixes: The clocks are rewritten to be conformant and precise." here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx

Comment: When it gives you the length of the pause, does it give it to you in nanoseconds? I'm still thinking a buggy `duration_cast`.

Answer (score 7):

Did you look at `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`?

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>
                (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

int total = 0;

void test()
{
    int foo = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) ++foo;
    total += foo;
}

int main ()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        total = 0;
        auto t = measure<std::chrono::nanoseconds>::execution(test);
        std::cout << "Calculated total = " << total << " in " << t << " ns." << std::endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives:

```
Calculated total = 1000 in 64 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 21 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 22 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 21 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 13 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 13 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 13 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 21 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 22 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 21 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 20 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 20 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 20 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 21 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 20 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 15 ns.
Calculated total = 1000 in 14 ns.
```

Comment: This code written as is outputs Calculated total = 1000 in 0 ns. on each loop call. Im using vs2013 community in release mode.

Comment: It looks like your code is right and VS is broken in some way. I don't currently have a Windows dev machine so can't test.

Comment: Can you see what happens if you remove the `duration_cast`? I saw some mentions of this being buggy in VS, though the examples I saw would cause compile problems, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Run the function 1000000 times and divide the result by 1000000.  You can use high precision timer, but it will be more prone to inaccuracies due to hardware quirkiness.

Edit:

You want a 1000,000 calls to the function itself and only one call to the timer:

```
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (size_t counter = 0; counter<1000000; ++counter)
         func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT>
        (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start)/1000000;
    return duration.count();
```

Comment: Doing this this way does output a number with 500,000 iterations I received 14 with high_res

Comment: I've added the idea into the answer because you can't do any formatting in the comments.

Comment: Agree that this is a good idea if you're looking for average times. But the high res timers on Intel CPUs should be able to give ns resolution, and the function in question should not get 0.

Comment: The higher the time resolution you ask of the hardware, the less accurate it will be.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Debug` does nothing, and your compiler may be able to figure that out, and consequently all you're doing is timing how fast you can call `now` twice in succession.

Do something to ensure that the code you're trying to time doesn't get optimized away. e.g. use its output somehow, or give it `__attribute__((noinline))` (if you don't mind timing the cost of the actual function call too) or something.

(also, you need your function to take substantially longer than the resolution on your clock if you want any useful amount of precision from your timings)

Comment: He also tried my example and got 0 timings, so this is not the issue, though I've definitely seen it happen in other naive examples. Always a good idea to have a measurable side-effect.

Comment: @sfjac: Your function does nothing too.

Comment: It sets a global variable that is then printed - the compiler can't optimize that away... Well, a really smart compiler could just set `total = 1000` and get rid of the function call, but it would have to do it for every call. I haven't seen one quite that smart. But it could definitely be optimizing out the loop in the function.

Comment: Of course he could check the assembly just to be sure. My guess, though, is that this is happening in debug mode. I suspect a VS bug.

Comment: I'mnot running in debug, I thought it was an issue and changed to release but still have the issue I'll play with it in a bit though and finish reading the rest of this

Comment: @Some1new: When I said "`Debug`" I was referring to your function (which you named `Debug`)

Comment: https://github.com/siscodev93/InputModification/blob/master/StringControl/Sample.cpp 
I added the entire project to github